# The inscription of the values ​of the pieces GD::Graph::pie

Tags: perl, gd-graph

[image]I can’t find any way how to sign the values ​​on the pieces of the pie chart.

[image]

Comment: What code do you use? How was the picture generated? What exactly do you mean by "sign the values"?

Comment: In a bar chart, this is show_values ​​=> 1

Comment: Please post code as text, not images.

Comment: you can put the values into the `@params` array then they will be displayed on the chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the values to the data in the `@params` array.

```
my @params = qw[param1 param2 param3];
my @values = qw[    45     25     30];

$params[$_] = "$params[$_] ($values[$_])" for 0 .. $#params;

my @data   = (\@params, \@values);
```